# Jxls | Not picking up xls template from the folder of the class.

Tags: java, jxls

I have a pretty basic question about the usage of jxls.

```
        XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
    transformer
            .transformXLS(
                    "dummy.xls",
                    beans, 
                    "dummyCreated.xls");
```

And this does not work.

The reason provided is that dummy.xls is not found. The dummy.xls is in the same location as the java class from which I have provided the snippet of code. If instead of dummy.xls I provide the fully qualified path i.e. D:\myfolder\theRestOfTheFolders\dummy.xls, then it works.

But, I need the code to work without providing the entire path. I need the code to work by picking up the xls from wherever the calling class is.

I am sure I am missing some small juggling of the java io library. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling around with jxls, I sort of gave up trying to make it pick up files from the location of the java file. So, I have given in and started passing it the actual file location.

```
<bean id="templateName" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="C:\Template.xls" />
</bean>
```

And then I made my code pick it up.

```
@Autowired
private String templateName;
```

And after that the code became simply.

```
transformer.transformXLS(templateName, beans, outputFileName);
```

This is working now. However, if anyone have a different suggested solution, please write back.